# android studio error - Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'

Tags: android-studio, react-native

While running the React Native Android app, then building the project the following error is shown:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:installDebug'.

Comment: cd android and ./gradlew clean and then run your app

Answer (score 0):

Go to android folder in your project and then type
`gradlew clean` for Windows and
`./gradlew clean` for Mac and Linux.  I use this method every time I encounter the same problem, and also when changing the package.json (add / remove library)

Answer (score -2):

Please remove build folder in /android/app and run build command again.
It worked for me.